# Subversion commit fails

Tags: svn, commit, ubuntu-10.10

I am running ubuntu 10.10, and have rabbitvcs & svn installed, I have created a repository & checked it out fine (local machine, using file://), but when i commit i get the error : "can't open /var/svn/repos/repository/db/txn-current-lock : Permission denied"

If i run it on the command line as root (sudo) all is well. I have looked in the conf & db files and applied all the potentially useful settings i can find on the internet, but i still cannot commit as myself!

Any ideas ??

Ta, NWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the owner of the repository to your user:

```
$ sudo chown -R [username] /var/svn/repos/repository
```

This should be enough if you are the only person using the repository, and it's only being used locally. If you need permissions for more local users, consider creating a separate group and granting this group write access to the repository. Finally, if you want to allow remote access to the repository, I recommend not using the local file protocol at all (even locally).

Comment: Yes its just me for now, so its all i need. I was hoping for a common configuration mistake that id made with an easy fix. Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure if you are ever reinstalling/etc that you remember to copy your repository directory as well.  Seeing as this is for yourself only putting it in your user directory solves headaches in the future.  As long as you remember to save it you should be fine though.  Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never been able to commit back to the repo I'd guess you really do have a permissions issue (the "Permission denied" thing ).  Does your user have permission to the subversion directory for this repository?  If you're using a local repository with "file://" you probably want the repository somewhere in your users home directory.

If you have been able to commit to the same place previously I'd recommend checking out a new clean version, make your changes there, and commit from the new check out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No i dont have permission, but i thought that was a configuration issue that svn would allow its set of users to write to it. I have accepted the answer of Adam as it does solve the problem.